# Trend line or line of best fit in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is there an "out of the box" way to automatically draw the trend line in pgfplots?

Below follows a basic illustration of a scatter graph with a line of best fit:

[image: a graph with a line of best fit]

Comment: For a linear regression see Section 4.22 of the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual.

Comment: Of course, how could I have missed that? Didn't find anything in the scatter plot section.

Comment: Not out of the box, but pgfplots can call gnuplot and you can create a simple script to fit an arbitrary function to your points. This might be more flexible depending on your dataset

Comment: I've always gone with doing the fit myself, then plotting the line using two endpoints (so I can, for example, fix the intercept). Not very elegant, but it works ...

Comment: Some time back I made a little example on how to fit with pgfplots+gnuplot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15487093/gnuplot-fit.tex

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Can be achieved using
`/pgfplots/table/create col/linear regression={⟨key-value-config⟩}`
documented in Section 4.22 of the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

---

Here's a slightly adapted version of the example from the manual. If you want to plot data directly from a file, replace the `\datatable` in the `\addplot` command with the file name.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=outer north east]
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
\addplot [thick, red] table[
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}
] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{\datatable};
\addlegendentry{$y(x)$}
\addlegendentry{%
$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
\pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```