# Use pgfplots to force linear regression through origin/zero

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using pgfplots to make a linear regression of some data. I know the curve should pass through zero (Hookes law).

data.csv:

```
F,delta
2.4525,0.6
4.905,1.05
7.3575,1.5
9.81,2.4
12.2625,2.5
14.715,3.35
17.1675,4
19.62,4.85
24.525,6.35
29.43,7.85
34.335,10.85
39.24,11.85
44.145,15.85
49.05,17.25
53.955,21.25
```

latexfile:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth, % Scale the plot to \linewidth
        ]
        \addplot 
          table[x=F,y=delta,col sep=comma, only marks] {data.csv};
        \addplot [no markers]
          table[x=F,y={create col/linear regression={y=delta}}, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
        \legend{Metingen,Lineaire regressie: $\delta=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot F$}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I force the linear regression to pass through the origin?

[image: Example render of the above code]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `gnuplot` as a backend to fit the function, similar to the approach given in [Adding values to pgfplot legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend). That approach has the advantage of letting you fit arbitrary functions, and of being much faster than the pure PGFPlots approach. It has the drawback of requiring a working installation of `gnuplot`, and having to compile with shell escape turned on.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
F,delta
2.4525,0.6
4.905,1.05
7.3575,1.5
9.81,2.4
12.2625,2.5
14.715,3.35
17.1675,4
19.62,4.85
24.525,6.35
29.43,7.85
34.335,10.85
39.24,11.85
44.145,15.85
49.05,17.25
53.955,21.25
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[xmin=0, ymin=0, legend pos=north west]

\addplot[only marks, mark size=1.8, black] table [col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    % Now call gnuplot to fit this data
    % The key is the raw gnuplot option
    % which allows to write a gnuplot script file
    \addlegendentry{Experiment 1}

\addplot+[raw gnuplot, red, mark=none, smooth] gnuplot {
    f(x)=a*x;
    % let gnuplot fit, using column 1 and 2 of the data file
    % using the following initial guesses
    a=1;
    set fit errorvariables;
    set datafile separator ",";
     fit f(x) 'data.csv' using 1:2 via a;
         % Next, plot the function and specify plot range
         % The range should be approx. the same as the test.dat x range
     plot [x=0:55] f(x);
    set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into
    print a, a_err; % Write the parameters to file
       };       
\addlegendentry[]{\pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters % Open the file Gnuplot wrote
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramA{\pgfplotsretval} % Get first element, save into \paramA
     $y=\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} \cdot x$    
}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's a beautiful solution. I already used `gnuplot` for plotting a NACA2412 airfoil in that document, so `gnuplot` isn't any problem :)