# pgfplots/gnuplot: How to find the curve-fitting function passing through certain points and plot it?

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, curve-fitting

Considering this code, I would like to know how to find the curve-fitting function passing through the first four points (i.e. `X=[0,3]`) and plot this function (e.g. the red dashed line in the desired output below).

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread{%
X Y
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 12
5 15
}\datatable

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=20]
    \addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Desired Output

[image]

Comment: Like this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57582/change-linestyle-within-a-plot-to-add-dashed-trendline

Comment: @percusse I am not sure, but I need the trendline to  be a unique curve `(X=[0,5])` with its own style and legend entry rather than an extension.

Comment: what is it to be extrapolated then? if you are looking for the closed form formula for the curve that won't be possible off-the-shelf

Comment: @percusse I think my question is not clear enough, but I need to deduce the fitting equation of the first four points, then use this equation to draw a new curve over `Y=[0,20]`.

Comment: @percusse I have revamped my question; you can find my desired output.

Comment: And how do you fit the curve ? Is there a formula ?

Comment: You can't do the curve fitting with Matlab/Python/whatever, and then plot the  resulting function with `pgfplots`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I can, but I wondered if such potential is existing in pgfplots since it would save me time.

Comment: I think only linear regression is implemented (see the section 4.24 in the manual).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for pointing this out. Additionally, is it possible to let `gnuplot` do this job when called by latex or not?

Comment: `pgfplots` has a `raw gnuplot` plot type, which I think let's you pass in most `gnuplot` code, so if `gnuplot` can do other type of curve fits, then you can probably do it. But I've never used `gnuplot`, or the `raw gnuplot` feature of `pgfplots`, much at all, so I don't really know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Many thanks for considering my comments; I am highly grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\addplot gnuplot` to do the curve fitting using the gnuplot backend, which allows you to use different domains for fitting and plotting the function. It also allows you to fit non-linear functions, like the quadratic function in this example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
X Y
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 12
5 15
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=0,ymax=20]
    \addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {data.dat};
    \addplot [no markers, red] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { % "raw gnuplot" allows us to use arbitrary gnuplot commands
            f(x) = a*x^2 + b;  % Define the function to fit
            a=1; b=1;          % Set reasonable starting values here
            % Select the x-range, the file, the columns (indexing starts at 1) and the variables for fitting
            fit [0:3] f(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via a,b; 
            plot [x=0:5] f(x); % Specify the range to plot
    };
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's awesome. You saved me a lot.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to write the fitting equation of `gnuplot` on the graph with an arrow pointing to the trendline?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend for one way of doing that

Comment: Many thanks, if you don't mind, I have another question. Why can't`gnuplot` read the data from `.csv` file unlike in case of `.dat` or `.txt` file? is it possible to let it read a `.csv` file?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a file with comma-separated columns? In that case, you have to use `set datafile separator ","` in the gnuplot code (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node173.html)

Comment: I couldn't be thankful more. Have a nice day.

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your work!