# Can pgfplots perform nonlinear regression?

Tags: pgfplots

Can `pgfplots` do nonlinear curve fitting?

In Excel, the fitting option is called log(agonist) vs response.

I couldn't find an option in the regression section of `pgfplots`.

Comment: PGFPlots can do logarithmic and semilogarithmic lines of best fit, but not general nonlinear regression (i.e. if you need other transformations, you'll have to transform the data yourself. This can be done on the fly in PGFPlots)

Comment: @Jake on wikipedia about Dose response, it says: 'Statistical analysis of dose-response curves may be performed by regression methods such as the probit model or logit model, or other methods such as the Spearman-Karber method. Empirical models based on nonlinear regression are usually preferred over the use of some transformation of the data that linearizes the dose-response relationship.' I think transforming the data wouldn't be advised for this.

Comment: Wikipedia about nonlinear curve fitting: "Some nonlinear regression problems can be moved to a linear domain by a suitable transformation of the model formulation. ...the choice to perform a nonlinear transformation must be informed by modeling considerations."

Comment: @Jake this model is based on Dose response though.

Comment: "Log(agonist)" sounds a lot like a logarithmic transform, not logit or probit.

Comment: Could you link to a resource that specifies what the excel function does? Or include some sample data and associated excel output?

Comment: @Jake here is an explanation on it.  You may be better suited at determining if it can be done with the transformation: http://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/curve-fitting/index.htm?reg_dr_stim.htm

Comment: @Jake I can get some sample data tomorrow.  The data I have right now is nonpublished research data so I cant post that.

Comment: @dustin you take the log of the agonist and plot it against the response. So a simple log-transform is what you need.

Comment: @dustin: The `log(agonist) vs response curve` in GraphPad is a logarithmically transformed sigmoid model (`f(x) = a + (b-a) / [1+10^(d*(log(c)-log(x)))]`). This model has to be fitted using nonlinear regression, which PGFPlots currently cannot do. You'll have to find the parameters using another program. You could do this using Gnuplot from within PGFPlots.

Comment: Very related: [Non-linear curve fitting with gnuplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29562/non-linear-curve-fitting-with-gnuplot)

Comment: @Jake I can delete the post or vote to close based on the link.  I think it may be better to close in case some use the same search criteria.

Comment: @dustin: I agree