# How can I fit the original data with exponential or polynomial functions via pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to plot the following data with a curve fitting via `pgfplots`.

It seems linear regression is not suitable for my case. So I would prefer to have exponential or polynomial curve fitting on these data. How can I implement it?

Below is the current code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }

\documentclass[border=1mm, png]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myData.dat}
X     Y 
2   275.68
3   1175.26
4   1351.60
5   1485.57
6   1583.30
7   1861.28
8   2095.39
9   2574.54
10  2841.74
11  2914.16
12  3965.12
13  3787.68
14  5294.83
21  10504.49
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{%
        ,width=10cm
        ,legend style={font=\footnotesize}
        }
    \begin{axis}[%
        ,xlabel=Numbers $N$ in \si{\gram\per\liter}
        ,ylabel=Ratio
        ,ymin=0
        ,xmin=0
        ,scaled y ticks=base 10:0
        ,legend cell align = left
        ,legend pos = north west
        ]
    \addplot[only marks] table {mydata.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Ratio of \emph{tfml} to \emph{gGN}}
    \addplot+[no markers,red] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{myData.dat};
    \addlegendentry{%
        Linear trend $(y=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb})$} %
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields:

> [image]

Comment: Did you take a look on how to use `gnuplot` in `pgfplots`? I guess, this kind of calculation needs some higher tool. Personally, I would recommend to calculate the curve you need via sageTeX and to plot it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! Such curve fitting is easy to implement via MS Excel or any other mathematical tools. However, when data sets are changing, the fitted curves have to be changed manually accordingly. Since both exponential and polynomial curve fitting can be converted into linear regression, so I guess there should be some implementation via `pgfplots` automatically.

Comment: Well, Excel is a powerful calculation tool... (not that I like it ;-) ). If there is something implemented here, you should be able to find it by the words "fitting", "regression", "approximation", "polynomial" or "Taylor" in the manuals of `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`. Please have a look! I didn't check.

Comment: Off topic: 1. `$-$` is a minus sign. Therefore I would not set the unit of your ratio in math-mode. (As units should not be set in square brackets (ISO & SI) and a "ratio" has the unit 1 by definition, I would leave it away completely.). 2. please make you code minimal. You just need `siunitx`, `pgfplots`, and `pgfplotstable` for this example.

Comment: I tried to search in the manual but didnot find exactly the solution. And I am not very familiar with how to convert it into linear regression in `pgfplots` myself. thank you for suggestions. Are you interested in editing my post so that I can learn from you?

Comment: One approach would be to transform the data so that a linear fit was appropriate - in this case you might take log(y), but then the value at x=2 looks like a big outlier.  See [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/tukey.html).

Comment: @LCFactorization: You can do this from within PGFPlots by using `gnuplot` in the background. See [Non-linear curve fitting with gnuplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29562/non-linear-curve-fitting-with-gnuplot) (this may be a duplicate of that question).

Comment: @Jake since I am asking whether it is possible by using pgfplots only, so solution with gnuplot may be a good option but not exactly the answer. So it is not a duplicate this way. Thank you

Comment: @Thruston, thank you , let me try. If it works and is not a duplicate, please also post an answer here.

Comment: @LCFactorization: PGFPlots can only do linear regression. The question "how can I linearize a polynomial / exponential equation?" seems more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you very much for editing it. I was also wondering how to simply use only one data table. You helped me with it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jake I also intend to post the TeX code into a paper preparing for  `arXiv.org`. The  TeXlive system in `arXiv.org` may not support `gnuplot`(but I am not very sure).

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Don't know why, the code `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.1}` doesn't work for me; I have to set it as at least `1.3 - 1.5` or there will be compiling error.

Comment: @Jake I now begin to agree with you that only `gnuplot` would solve my problem easily. thank you!

Comment: @LCFactorization `1.10` is what I wrote. Maybe you have to update your packages. You can add `\listfiles` in your preamble in order to read your current version in the `.log`-file. Just set the `compat`-number to your version. However, 1.10 is the most recent: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots

Comment: I use the old-styled version partly because I want to keep my LaTeX source code compatible with the `TeXLive` of `arXiv.org`. Thank you. I now realized this is a version number; I checked and found that only 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 work for me now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an attempt via polynomial fit and the use of `gnuplot`. Therefore this requires one to compile the code with shell-escape enabled, and `gnuplot` has to be installed on your system.

[image]

**Edit:** The OP finds how to find the actually parameters after curve fitting. The answer is  here: [show fitted values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/%E2%80%A6) which needs two lines of code

```
set print "parameters.dat"; % Open a file to save the parameters into
print a, b;                 % Write the parameters to file
```

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}%[miktex]%[shell]
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
X     Y   
2   275.68
3   1175.26
4   1351.60
5   1485.57
6   1583.30
7   1861.28
8   2095.39
9   2574.54
10  2841.74
11  2914.16
12  3965.12
13  3787.68
14  5294.83
21  10504.49
    };
\end{filecontents}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={Numbers [N,\si{\gram\per\liter}]},
    ylabel={Ratio $[-]$},
    ymin =0,
    ytick = {200,2000,4000,6000,8000,10000},
        y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},
    scaled y ticks=base 10:0,
    legend cell align = left,
    legend pos = north west]
    \addplot[only marks] table[x =X,y =Y]{data.csv};
    \addlegendentry{Ratio of {\em tfml} to {\em gGN}}
% linear curve fitting
    \addplot+[no markers,red] table[row sep=\\,
    y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
    {data.csv};
    \addlegendentry{%
        linear trend $\left(y=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona} \cdot x
        \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}\right)$} %
% polynomial fit 
    \addplot [no markers, blue] gnuplot [raw gnuplot] { % allows arbitrary gnuplot commands
            f(x) = a*x**2+b*x;     % Define the function to fit
            a=260;b=-270;          % Set reasonable starting values here
            fit f(x) 'data.csv' u 1:2 via a,b; % Select the file, starts at col 1 and two variables
            plot [x=2:21] f(x);    % Specify the range to plot
            set print "parameters.dat";  % Open a file to save the parameters
            print a, b;                  % Write the parameters to file
    };
   \addlegendentry{\pgfplotstableread{parameters.dat}\parameters % Open the file Gnuplot wrote
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{0}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramA{\pgfplotsretval} % Get first element, save into \paramA
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of\parameters \pgfmathsetmacro\paramB{\pgfplotsretval}
 polynomial fit: $y=\pgfmathprintnumber{\paramA} x^2 \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\paramB} x $
}
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you. Is it possible to explicitly show the fitted values of `a` and `b` in the legendentry?

Comment: The answer is probably here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29633/adding-values-to-pgfplot-legend  thanks

Comment: Yes, you got it. I was searching the auxiliary file, to see if any info was left in *.plot.gnuplot and *.plot.table file, but none. Then your finding prompt me to try. Yes, you find the answer.

Comment: would you please edit your answer with legendentry updates?

Comment: My pleasure, coming up soon.