# How to retrieve regression line to plot normal distribution upon it

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3d

This is a continuation of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142?noredirect=1#comment1147448_456142) question.

Below is my current output and problematic area is that brown curve.
[image]

I am trying to plot pdf as a 2D graph standing upon the regression line (red).

I am able to place it on a specific point, but I want to place upon the linear regression line calculated by tikz, at expected value of Y for a particular x, which would be on the line (Y = ax + b).  Since reg line is automatically calculated, I am unable to fetch and place. Is there a way to do that or should I have another table or manual regression line drawn (please also specify how to do that here, if that should be the case)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z m
2.2 14 0 0
2.7 23 0 0
3 13 0 0
3.55 22 0 0
4 15 0 0
4.5 20 0 0
4.75 28 0 0
5.5 23 0 0
}\datatable

% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fcirc}
{%          
          \begin{scope}[local frame]
              \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
                    \fill circle(0.1);
              \end{scope}   
          \end{scope}
}%
\newcommand{\GetLocalFrame}
{
    \path let \p1=(     $(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p2=(    $(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p3=(   $(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)$   )  % these look like axes line paths
    in \pgfextra  %pgfextra is to execute below code before constructing the above path 
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}
        {   
            veclen(\x1,\y1)/veclen(\x2,\y2)  
        }
        \globaldefs=1\relax   % I think this makes all assignments global
        \tikzset
        {
            local frame/.style/.expanded =
            {   
                x   =  {   (\x1,\y1)    },
                y   =  {    (\ratio*\x2,\ratio*\y2)     },
                z   =   {     (\x3,\y3)     }
            }
        }
    }; 
}

\tikzset
{
    declare function={
            % normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
}


\begin{document}

\section{table using raw data in 3D}

The below diagram tries to replicate in 3D, the Figure 12.3 found in \cite{devore} , page 472 \\

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/trend-line-or-line-of-best-fit-in-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}
    [   
        view={140}{50},
        samples=200,
        samples y=0, 
        xmin=1,xmax=6, ymin=5,ymax=40, zmin=0, zmax=10,
        % ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
        clip=false, axis lines = middle,
        area plot/.style=   % for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph
        {
            fill opacity=0.5,
            draw=none,
            fill=orange,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        }
    ]
    % read out the transformation done by pgfplots

    \GetLocalFrame
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
        \addplot3[only marks, fill=cyan,mark=fcirc] table {\datatable};
    \end{scope}

    \def\X{2.7}
    \def\Y{23}
    \addplot3[thick, red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] {\datatable}; % compute a linear regression from the input table
    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (\X,\Y+10,12.5) node[right]{$(x_1,y_1)$} ..controls (0,5) .. (\X,\Y,0);
    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (9,30,20) node[left, align=right]{\scriptsize True Regression Line\\ \scriptsize $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$} .. controls (5,2.5) .. (5,22.7,0); 
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt}, xshift=0.5mm] (\X,\Y-0.1,0) to (\X,17,0) node[left, xshift=5mm, yshift=-1mm]{\scriptsize 1}; % brace 

    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (1,17.1) to (\X,17.1);
    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (\X,17.1) -- (\X,5);
    \node[above] at (\X,4) {$x_1$};
    \node[right, align=left,yshift=0.5mm] at (1,17.1) {$E(Y|x_1)=\mu_{Y.x_1}$};

    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254497
    \addplot3 [area plot, domain=(14-5):(14+5)] (2.2, x, {30*normal(x, 14, 2)});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}




  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{devore} Jay. L Devore {\em Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences} 8th Edition.
  \end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Not exactly an MWE but my current whole document, as I am building this graph step by step, so you could also know the context to optimize and integrate with existing plot efficiently.

I already referred and referring [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254497) but already spent too much time trying to integrate as something fails here or there.

**Update (problems still exist):**  For time being, I have managed to draw manual regression line and plotting on that, however, I am unable to draw a single vertical line. I am some how unable to get the peak value of dist to pass as z (instead have passed hardcoded value 5), and also weirdly, the line does not cross the sample behind the curve which gives a weird 3d perspective.

**Current output:**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z m
2.2 14 0 0
2.7 23 0 0
3 13 0 0
3.55 22 0 0
4 15 0 0
4.5 20 0 0
4.75 28 0 0
5.5 23 0 0
}\datatable

% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fcirc}
{%          
          \begin{scope}[local frame]
              \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
                    \fill circle(0.1);
              \end{scope}   
          \end{scope}
}%
\newcommand{\GetLocalFrame}
{
    \path let \p1=(     $(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p2=(    $(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p3=(   $(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)$   )  % these look like axes line paths
    in \pgfextra  %pgfextra is to execute below code before constructing the above path 
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}
        {   
            veclen(\x1,\y1)/veclen(\x2,\y2)  
        }
        \globaldefs=1\relax   % I think this makes all assignments global
        \tikzset
        {
            local frame/.style/.expanded =
            {   
                x   =  {   (\x1,\y1)    },
                y   =  {    (\ratio*\x2,\ratio*\y2)     },
                z   =   {     (\x3,\y3)     }
            }
        }
    }; 
}

\tikzset
{
    declare function={
            % normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
}


\begin{document}

\section{table using raw data in 3D}

The below diagram tries to replicate in 3D, the Figure 12.3 found in \cite{devore} , page 472 \\

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/trend-line-or-line-of-best-fit-in-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}
    [   
        view={130}{50},
        samples=200,
        samples y=0, 
        xmin=1,xmax=6, ymin=5,ymax=40, zmin=0, zmax=10,
        % ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
        clip=false, axis lines = middle,
        area plot/.style=   % for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph
        {
            fill opacity=0.5,
            draw=none,
            fill=orange,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        }
    ]
    % read out the transformation done by pgfplots

    \GetLocalFrame
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
        \addplot3[only marks, fill=cyan,mark=fcirc] table {\datatable};
    \end{scope}

    \def\X{2.7}
    \def\Y{23}

    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (\X,\Y+10,12.5) node[right]{$(x_1,y_1)$} ..controls (0,5) .. (\X,\Y,0);
    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (9,30,20) node[left, align=right]{\scriptsize True Regression Line\\ \scriptsize $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$} .. controls (5,2.5) .. (5,22.7,0); 
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt}, xshift=0.5mm] (\X,\Y-0.1,0) to (\X,17,0) node[left, xshift=5mm, yshift=-1mm]{\scriptsize 1}; % brace 

    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (1,17.1) to (\X,17.1);
    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (\X,17.1) -- (\X,5);
    \node[above] at (\X,4) {$x_1$};
    \node[right, align=left,yshift=0.5mm] at (1,17.1) {$E(Y|x_1)=\mu_{Y.x_1}$};


    % regression line - lets try to manually calculate
    % \addplot3[thick, red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] {\datatable}; % compute a linear regression from the input table
    \def\a{2.62}
    \def\b{9.85}
    \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, red, domain=1:6] (x, {\a*(x)+\b}, 0);

    % normal distribution above the interesting regression point, that is expected value of Y for a given x
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254497
    \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\a*(\X)+\b}
    \addplot3 [area plot, domain=0:40)] (\X, x, {100*normal(x, \valueY, 3)});

    \draw [thick] (\X,\valueY,0) to (\X,\valueY,5);  %HOW TO GET TO PEAK OF DIST AND ALSO OVER THE BLUE SAMPLE LYING BEHIND THIS LINE

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}




  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{devore} Jay. L Devore {\em Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences} 8th Edition.
  \end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Can you please help? Also how to reduce the font size of axes? They appear too big.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulations to what you've achieved! I find it amazing. The last step is almost trivial in comparison. You know the function you plot, which suggests to just draw `\draw [thick] (\X,\valueY,0) to (\X,\valueY,{100*normal(\valueY, \valueY, 3)});`. As for the background/foreground issue, this can be resolved by adding `set layers` and drawing the line on the `axis foreground` (say).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z m
2.2 14 0 0
2.7 23 0 0
3 13 0 0
3.55 22 0 0
4 15 0 0
4.5 20 0 0
4.75 28 0 0
5.5 23 0 0
}\datatable

% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fcirc}{%          
          \begin{scope}[expand style={local frame}{\MyLocalFrame},local frame]
          \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
            \fill circle(0.1);
          \end{scope}   
          \end{scope}
}%
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64237/121799
\tikzset{expand style/.code n args={2}{\tikzset{#1/.style/.expanded={#2}}}}
\newcommand{\GetLocalFrame}{
    \path let \p1=($(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$), \p2=($(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)$),
    \p3=($(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)$) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}{veclen(\x1,\y1)/veclen(\x2,\y2)}
    \xdef\MyLocalFrame{   
                x   =  {   (\x1,\y1)    },
                y   =  {    (\ratio*\x2,\ratio*\y2)     },
                z   =   {     (\x3,\y3)     }
            }
    }; 
}


\tikzset
{
    declare function={
            % normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
}


\begin{document}

\section{table using raw data in 3D}

The below diagram tries to replicate in 3D, the Figure 12.3 found in \cite{devore} , page 472 \\

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/trend-line-or-line-of-best-fit-in-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}
    [set layers,   
        view={130}{50},
        samples=200,
        samples y=0, 
        xmin=1,xmax=6, ymin=5,ymax=40, zmin=0, zmax=10,
        % ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
        clip=false, axis lines = middle,
        area plot/.style=   % for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph
        {
            fill opacity=0.5,
            draw=none,
            fill=orange,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        }
    ]
    % read out the transformation done by pgfplots

    \GetLocalFrame
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
        \addplot3[only marks, fill=cyan,mark=fcirc] table {\datatable};
    \end{scope}

    \def\X{2.7}
    \def\Y{23}

    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (\X,\Y+10,12.5) node[right]{$(x_1,y_1)$} ..controls (0,5) .. (\X,\Y,0);
    \draw [-{Latex[length=4mm, width=2mm]}] (9,30,20) node[left, align=right]{\scriptsize True Regression Line\\ \scriptsize $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$} .. controls (5,2.5) .. (5,22.7,0); 
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=3pt}, xshift=0.5mm] (\X,\Y-0.1,0) to (\X,17,0) node[left, xshift=5mm, yshift=-1mm]{\scriptsize 1}; % brace 

    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (1,17.1) to (\X,17.1);
    \draw [thick,dash pattern={on 7pt off 2pt on 1pt off 3pt}] (\X,17.1) -- (\X,5);
    \node[above] at (\X,4) {$x_1$};
    \node[right, align=left,yshift=0.5mm] at (1,17.1) {$E(Y|x_1)=\mu_{Y.x_1}$};


    % regression line - lets try to manually calculate
    % \addplot3[thick, red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] {\datatable}; % compute a linear regression from the input table
    \def\a{2.62}
    \def\b{9.85}
    \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, red, domain=1:6] (x, {\a*(x)+\b}, 0);

    % normal distribution above the interesting regression point, that is expected value of Y for a given x
    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254484/how-to-make-a-graph-of-heteroskedasticity-with-tikz-pgf/254497
    \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\a*(\X)+\b}
    \addplot3 [area plot, domain=0:40)] (\X, x, {100*normal(x, \valueY, 3)});
    \pgfonlayer{axis foreground}
    \draw [thick] (\X,\valueY,0) to (\X,\valueY,{100*normal(\valueY, \valueY, 3)});  
    \endpgfonlayer
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{devore} Jay. L Devore {\em Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences} 8th Edition.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you marmot. Just another issue unresolved as noted in question, that  the circle behind the graph is weirdly shown as above the line. In reality, the graph is front of that circle, so middle line we just drew, should be crossing over that circle. The circle I am talking about is the only one behind graph near and below number 10.

Comment: @PaariVendhan Sorry, didn't read that part and fixed it now.

Comment: great, thank you. why was that happening, btw?

Comment: @PaariVendhan This is rather delicate. pgfplots (like Ti*k*Z) does not have a true 3D engine. So if you do one `\addlplot3` after another, the second one will be always on top. Things that get done with Ti*k*Z commands like `\draw` will be done anyway after the plots are done. To this end, there are the layers, which allow you to draw objects in the order you want to. If you wish this to be done automatically, consider switching to `asymptote`.

Comment: oh that would be another steep learning curve I guess. The change you have made, some how pushes the graph lower, leaving a wide gap as shown [here](https://i.postimg.cc/Nj7N3fMs/2018-10-22-21h23-31.png). Why would that happen? I think ```set layers``` is doing that, but removing that creates error. Please help