# pgfonlayer pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, 3d, tikz-3d

This is the continuation of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456207/how-to-retrieve-regression-line-to-plot-normal-distribution-upon-it/) issue and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456260/weird-error-when-including-tikz-in-a-figure/), where I try to draw normal distributions along the regression line for different x values in 3D.

The problem now is, for all distributions, I try to plot a line showing mean value of distribution, and then also a line from actual (xn,yn) to the regression line. But the pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement is acting weird (I used that to read X value from a table). Only one vertical line is drawn and nothing else. Kindly help.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z m
2.2 14 0 0
2.7 23 0 0
3 13 0 0
3.55 22 0 0
4 15 0 0
4.5 20 0 0
4.75 28 0 0
5.5 23 0 0
}\datatablet

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fcirc}
{%          
    \begin{scope}[expand style={local frame}{\MyLocalFrame},local frame]
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
            \fill circle(0.1);
        \end{scope}   
    \end{scope}
}% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64237/121799
\tikzset{expand style/.code n args={2}{\tikzset{#1/.style/.expanded={#2}}}}
\newcommand{\GetLocalFrame}
{
    \path let \p1=(     $(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p2=(    $(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p3=(   $(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)$   )  % these look like axes line paths
    in \pgfextra  %pgfextra is to execute below code before constructing the above path 
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}
        {   
            veclen(\x1,\y1)/veclen(\x2,\y2)  
        }
        \xdef\MyLocalFrame{   
                x   =  {   (\x1,\y1)    },
                y   =  {    (\ratio*\x2,\ratio*\y2)     },
                z   =   {     (\x3,\y3)     }
            }
    }; 
}

\tikzset
{
    declare function={
        % normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
    }
}


\begin{document}

\section{table using raw data in 3D}

The below diagram tries to replicate in 3D, the Figure 12.3 found in \cite{devore} , page 472 \\


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/trend-line-or-line-of-best-fit-in-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}
    [ set layers,   
        view={130}{50},
        samples=200,
        samples y=0, 
        xmin=1,xmax=6, ymin=5,ymax=40, zmin=0, zmax=10,
        % ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
        clip=false, axis lines = middle,
        area plot/.style=   % for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph
        {
            fill opacity=0.25,
            draw=none,
            fill=orange,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        }
    ]
    % read out the transformation done by pgfplots

    \GetLocalFrame
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
        \addplot3[only marks, fill=cyan,mark=fcirc] table {\datatablet};
    \end{scope}

    \def\X{2.7}
    \def\Y{23}

    \def\a{2.62}
    \def\b{9.85}
    \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, red, domain=1:6] (x, {\a*(x)+\b}, 0);



    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{X}\of\datatablet\as\S{%
        \edef\i{\pgfplotstablerow}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\a*(\S)+\b}
        \addplot3 [area plot, domain=0:40)] (\S, x, {100*normal(x, \valueY, 3)}); 
        % Below commented lines generate error
        \pgfonlayer{axis foreground}
            \draw [thick] (\S,\valueY,0) to (\S,\valueY,{100*normal(\valueY, \valueY, 3)});
            \draw [thick] (\S,\valueY,0) to (\S,{\a*(\S)+\b},0);  
        \endpgfonlayer         
    }    


        \node [below=1cm, align=flush center,text width=8cm] at (5,30,0)
        {
            The Probability Distribution $f(Y|x_1)$
        };    
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture} 





  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{devore} Jay. L Devore {\em Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences} 8th Edition.
  \end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Sorry about too elaborate MWE, as this is an ongoing development with lots of tweaking.

Comment: +1. You're saying "Below commented lines generate error" but I can't see a commented line nor an error.

Comment: For the record: [Jake's patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/95441) is now incorporated in v3.1 of TikZ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the mysterious expanding universe of `pgfplots`. A standard trick does the job, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{3d,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta}

% small fix for canvas is xy plane at z % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
    \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
    \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
    \tikz@canvas@is@plane}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z m
2.2 14 0 0
2.7 23 0 0
3 13 0 0
3.55 22 0 0
4 15 0 0
4.5 20 0 0
4.75 28 0 0
5.5 23 0 0
}\datatablet

% ref: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456138/marks-do-not-appear-in-3d-for-3d-scatter-plot/456142
\pgfdeclareplotmark{fcirc}
{%          
    \begin{scope}[expand style={local frame}{\MyLocalFrame},local frame]
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
            \fill circle(0.1);
        \end{scope}   
    \end{scope}
}% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64237/121799
\tikzset{expand style/.code n args={2}{\tikzset{#1/.style/.expanded={#2}}}}
\newcommand{\GetLocalFrame}
{
    \path let \p1=(     $(1,0,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p2=(    $(0,1,0)-(0,0,0)$   ), \p3=(   $(0,0,1)-(0,0,0)$   )  % these look like axes line paths
    in \pgfextra  %pgfextra is to execute below code before constructing the above path 
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}
        {   
            veclen(\x1,\y1)/veclen(\x2,\y2)  
        }
        \xdef\MyLocalFrame{   
                x   =  {   (\x1,\y1)    },
                y   =  {    (\ratio*\x2,\ratio*\y2)     },
                z   =   {     (\x3,\y3)     }
            }
    }; 
}

\tikzset
{
    declare function={
            % normal(\m,\s)=1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
            normal(\x,\m,\s) = 1/(2*\s*sqrt(pi))*exp(-(\x-\m)^2/(2*\s^2));
        }
}


\begin{document}

\section{table using raw data in 3D}

The below diagram tries to replicate in 3D, the Figure 12.3 found in \cite{devore}, page 472 \\
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
\pgfplotsset{
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            name=#1-\coordindex,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11251/trend-line-or-line-of-best-fit-in-pgfplots
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\begin{axis}
    [ set layers,   
        view={130}{50},
        samples=200,
        samples y=0, 
        xmin=1,xmax=6, ymin=5,ymax=40, zmin=0, zmax=10,
        % ytick=\empty,xtick=\empty,ztick=\empty,
        clip=false, axis lines = middle,
        area plot/.style=   % for this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53794/plotting-several-2d-functions-in-a-3d-graph
        {
            fill opacity=0.25,
            draw=none,
            fill=orange,
            mark=none,
            smooth
        }
    ]
    % read out the transformation done by pgfplots

    \GetLocalFrame
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
        \addplot3[only marks, fill=cyan,mark=fcirc,nodes near coords={},
        nodes near coords style={anchor=center,opacity=0,inner sep=2pt},
         name nodes near coords=blob] table {\datatablet};
    \end{scope}

    \def\X{2.7}
    \def\Y{23}

    \def\a{2.62}
    \def\b{9.85}
    \addplot3 [samples=2, samples y=0, red, domain=1:6] (x, {\a*(x)+\b}, 0);



    \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{X}\of\datatablet\as\S{%
        \edef\i{\pgfplotstablerow}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\valueY{\a*(\S)+\b}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i+1}
        \addplot3 [area plot, domain=0:40)] (\S, x, {100*normal(x, \valueY, 3)});
        % Below commented lines generate error
        \edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfonlayer{axis foreground}
            \noexpand\draw [thick] (\S,\valueY,0) 
            coordinate (i-\i) to (\S,\valueY,{100*normal(\valueY, \valueY, 3)});
        \noexpand\endpgfonlayer}
        \temp
        \xdef\imax{\i}
    }    


        \node [below=1cm, align=flush center,text width=8cm] at (5,30,0)
        {
            The Probability Distribution $f(Y|x_1)$
        };    
\end{axis}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\imax}
\draw[thick] (i-\X) -- (blob-\X);
\end{tikzpicture} 

  \begin{thebibliography}{1}
  \bibitem{devore} Jay. L Devore {\em Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences} 8th Edition.
  \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @marmot and sure, i missed because that was in a separate style plot and this was my another source content not yet updated with that change. btw, the horizontal lines from blue circles to red line is still not done?

Comment: I just updated the question with newer \GetLocalFrame.

Comment: @PaariVendhan Thanks for the update but which horizontal lines are you talking about?

Comment: I also wanted the lines from blue circles to the red line indicating the error. " \draw [thick] (\S,\valueY,0) to (\S,{\a*(\S)+\b},0);  " in my code seem to be not working

Comment: and even with updated \GetLocalFrame, your change here is still needed as it is right @marmot?

Comment: @PaariVendhan Yes, you need the `\edef`-`\noexpand` trick and I understand now what you want but I am in a rush and will do it in 2.5 hours unless someone else does it before...

Comment: @PaariVendhan The issue is that the horizontal line has length 0 in the way you construct it. You draw a line with the same start and end points. However, you seem to want to connect the blue circles. This can be done e.g. with `nodes near coords`. I will be back in 80 mins or so.

Comment: not among blue circles, but from each blue circle to its corresponding spot on the red line. Its to indicate the error distance for regression.

Comment: yes I just noticed. Instead of using Y data from the table I was using same point. My bad. But how do we get 2nd element as well from datatable?

Comment: @PaariVendhan Yes, and I took care of that in my update.

Comment: wow, it works now. great @marmot, thank you very much.

Comment: just a small issue. you seem to have connected the height (or vertical line) with error distance (horizontal line). can we decouple them? i would like to have different styles for them, thick was just temporary, did not think you would connect them in single line. I tried to decouple but its giving me error.

Comment: @PaariVendhan I'm in a seminar now but the horizontal lines are drawn with `\draw[thick] (i-\X) -- (blob-\X);`. You should be able to put any style there. Just add `red` to see what I mean.

Comment: oh got it, I missed it caz it was separated from the part I was focussing on.